# How define a unique "plugins" path to all apps in 1.3?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-1.3

In 1.2 i  used:

```
$pluginPaths = array(CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS. 'vendors' . DS.
```

'plugins' . DS);

But.. in 1.3 we have the new plugins path, and i believe thats not
necessary the $pluginsPaths manual declaration if i  have:

```
    if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
                    //define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT);
                    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DS .
    "libs2");

}
```

I saved my plugin inside the "plugins path"...
But i have not sucess in:

```
var $components = 'Plugin.Component';
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks, Celso.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need [this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3#Configuration-and-application-bootstrapping-1568).